# Show that there is no non constant analytic function in $\overline{B(0,1)} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}||z| \leq 1\}$ which is real valued on the boundary.

Tags: complex-analysis

It is a question from Bak and newman, the hint given to me was show that if $F(z)$ is a function on $B(0,1)$ such that $F(z) \neq 0$ on $B(0,1)$ and $|F(z)|$ is a constant on $C(0,1)$, then $F(z)$ is a constant on $B(0,1)$, then consider the function $F(z) = e^{if(z)}$

I know somehow we need to use maximum modulus principle, however, the hint made me confused, any help will be appreciated.

And in addition, when the hint says on $C(0,1)$, does that mean on the boundary of $C$ or actually means the whole region $C$?

Comment: What does real valued on  $C(0,1)$ mean?

Comment: Not too sure either

Comment: If we don't know what is the region $C(0,1)$ we cannot help you.

Comment: This question is in which chapter of the book?

Comment: I think $C(0,1)$ is the boundary of the open disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that such a function $f$ exists. Define$$g(z)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         f(z) & \mbox{if $|z| \leq 1$};\\
        {\overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})}} & \mbox{if $|z| \geq 1$}.\end{array} \right. 
$$

Then by Schwarz Reflection Principle $g$ is an entire function. Moreover $g$ is bounded. Hence $g$ is a constant which implies that $f$ is a constant as well.